# Creating own intellisense

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, project, intellisense

Going to create a new MVC project that contains a textbox with some kind of code editor, with Visual Studio that must be able to feel if what you are writing is either Javascript/HTML/C#,And it should be able to show you examples of what you are starting to write...for example "sel" could be "select" and show you if what you writing is valid or invalid.
Mostly just curious if its possible to link in some kind of library for Visual Studio that have alot of commands of example: Javascript code.

This is my first post here and i hope you'll understand what i mean, if you dont plz pm me or ask me more :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx#Extensibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. http://avalonedit.net/documentation/
It is WPF based and has syntax highlighting and multiple language support.

Comment: Yes this seems to be what we are looking for :) thanks!